# Can I bound an ELF to a particular CPU

Tags: multiprocessing, elf

After checking the ELF format, it seems that there is no region indicates which CPU will execute this file.

My question is:

Can we assign a particular CPU to an ELF? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we assign a particular CPU to an ELF?

No.

> if i want to assign a program to a particular cpu, how can i do it?

Depends on the OS.

> instead of use Linux command

On Linux, you can call [sched_setaffinity](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) to bind a process to a set of CPUs, or [pthread_setaffinity_np](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) to bind a thread to a set of CPUs (note: neither call is portable to other OSes).

Comment: thanks for replying! so, if i want to assign a program to a particular cpu, how can i do it? I mean, can we change sth in code or  the .S, .O files, instead of use Linux command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very helpful!